# ODE with time lag

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

We can build a population growth model based on the following hypothesis:

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=\text{births}-\text{deaths}$$
$$\text{births}=aN(t), a>0$$
$$\text{deaths}=bN(t), b>0$$

We can find its solution:

$$N(t)=N_0e^{(a-b)t}$$

Aside from whether or not it is a good idea, the hypothesis about the births can be replaced by the following:

$$\text{births}=aN(t-p), a>0, p>0$$

The differential equation becomes:

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=aN(t-p)+-bN(t)$$

Can the solution to this ODE be written in closed form?

I know basic calculus.

Comment: It is no longer an ODE, it is a DDE. Solutions depend not on an initial value at $t=0$, but on an initial history over $[-p,0]$. No general solution formula exists, but you can find special cases if you try exponential functions.

Comment: You can compute solutions for given initial conditions by forward propagation. First your solve for $t\in[0,p]$ given your initial condition, then $t\in[p,2p]$, etc. etc.

Comment: You can also obtain the close form solution of $N(t)$ on certain intervals, say $t \in [0, T]$. If you're lucky, you may find a close form solution for a general $N(t)$.